# How to get custom attribute of select's option in angularjs?

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

This is how my html looks like

```
<select name="currency_advance" ng-model="currency" ng-change="put_currency()">
    <?php foreach ($currency as $c) { ?>
      <option data-type="<?php echo $c->symbol; ?>" value="<?php echo $c->alphaCode; ?>" >
       <?php echo $c->alphaCode; ?> - <?php echo $c->currency; ?>
      </option>
     <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Now I can get option value in angularjs's controller using put_currency function, but now I also need to get the custom attribute "data-type" value.

How can I accomplish this? Anyone please help me?

**UPDATE**

Now I am generating select field from javascript. But now problem is I need to set and get another value that is called symbol of currency. Previously I was using custom tag data-type to get the currency symbol. How can I set and get custom tag value in angularJS way?

```
<select name="currency_advance" ng-model="currency" ng-options="data.code as data.code + ' - ' + data.currency for data in data">
```

Comment: Don't store business logic data in the DOM. That's a blatant disregard to separation of concerns and is not the Angular way. Instead, use an ng-repeat directive and store the actual application logic data in JavaScript. It's easier to test, it's more readable, it creates better architecture and generally it makes more sense.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum -- But I don't want to use any XHR in this point. Also I don't know to do this in angular way

Comment: You don't need XHR, you can inject the JSON object encoded in the same page. It seems like you're missing more fundamental understanding for structuring a good Angular app - I suggest you take the high way and learn the technology properly first (Also, make sure you understand JavaScript and PHP themselves before you start working with Frameworks). I suggest http://egghead.io which has a good and canonical Angular tutorial

Comment: If you don't want to do things the "agnular way" then you shouldn't be using angular. You'll be fighting an uphill battle the whole way and will be making things harder for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In your ng-options do this:

ng-options="data as data.code + ' - ' + data.currency for data in data"

notice the first thing is data instead of data.code. This makes your entire "data" object available under $scope.currency. The way you were doing it before, only the "code" would be under $scope.currency. You can then easily get to the symbol by accessing $scope.currency.symbol.

In general, you should NEVER need to store data in the DOM using custom data-* attributes.